# How Gradle BOM import support resolve dependency version added in plugin dynamically?

Tags: gradle, spring-boot-gradle-plugin

I use Spring Boot and [Spring Boot Dependency Management Plugin](https://docs.spring.io/dependency-management-plugin/docs/current/reference/html/) which helps me use dependencies from Spring Boot BOM. However, **Gradle support for BOM** import since **version 5.0.** I made a decision to migrate to [Gradle built-in BOM import support](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/platforms.html). But I run into the issue:
I use custom Gradle plugin with dynamically added dependency:

```
open class MyCustomPlugin : Plugin<Project> {
    override fun apply(project: Project): Unit = project.run {
        project.dependencies.add("jooqRuntime", "org.postgresql:postgresql")
    }
}
```

This plugis depends on another plugin

```
dependencies {
implementation("nu.studer:gradle-jooq-plugin:4.1")}
```

Thus I could get the version of PostgreSQL from this plugin. Now I cannot do the same. How can I resolve dependency added in plugin dynamically?

Answer (score 1):

Spring's dependency management plugin is a bit heavy handed. It touches **all** configurations as you can see [here](https://github.com/spring-gradle-plugins/dependency-management-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/io/spring/gradle/dependencymanagement/DependencyManagementPlugin.java#L50..L51) with the usage of `all()` call.

The native Gradle solution is optimized or "smarter" and only "touches" the configurations it needs to. You can learn more about differences in [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AADeX1AEmzU) talk.

So the solution here is to import the BOM or platform as Gradle calls it for the `jooqRuntime` configuration. This can either be done in your project:

```
dependencies {
    "jooqRuntime"(platform("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:2.2.5.RELEASE")
}
```

or in the plugin directly (Java example):

```
public class MyCustomPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {

    @Override
    public void execute(Project project) {
        DependencyHandler dependencies = project.getDependencies();
        dependencies.add("jooqRuntime", dependencies.platform("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:2.2.5.RELEASE"));
    }

}
```